# String.Format - How can I format to x digits (regardless of decimal place)?

Tags: c#, string-formatting, decimal-point

I need to format a floating point number to x characters (6 in my case including the decimal point). My output also needs to include the sign of the number

So given the inputs, here are the expected outputs

```
1.23456   => +1.2345

-12.34567 => -12.345

-0.123456 => -0.1234

1234.567  => +1234.5
```

Please assume there is always a decimal place before the last character. I.e. there will be no  `12345.6` number input - the input will always be less than or equal to `9999.9`.

I'm thinking this has to be done conditionally.

Comment: what do you expect for 1234567.00? +1234567?

Comment: @BurundukXP A little more clarification : please assume there will be no input higher than 9999

Comment: @Simon, can you confirm that you desire truncation, and not rounding?

Comment: Either is fine, rounding or truncation wasn't the issue here, simply the formatting.

Comment: @Simon I posted an answer that should work for all inputs, and all x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a transparent way to do it without format strings (except for "F"):

```
  static void Main()
  {
     double y = 1.23456;
     Console.WriteLine(FormatNumDigits(y,5));
     y= -12.34567;
     Console.WriteLine(FormatNumDigits(y,5));
     y = -0.123456;
     Console.WriteLine(FormatNumDigits(y,5));
     y = 1234.567;
     Console.WriteLine(FormatNumDigits(y,5));

     y = 0.00000234;
     Console.WriteLine(FormatNumDigits(y,5));

     y = 1.1;
     Console.WriteLine(FormatNumDigits(y,5));
  }


  public string FormatNumDigits(double number, int x) {
     string asString = (number >= 0? "+":"") + number.ToString("F50",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

     if (asString.Contains('.')) {
        if (asString.Length > x + 2) {
           return asString.Substring(0, x + 2);
        } else {
           // Pad with zeros
           return asString.Insert(asString.Length, new String('0', x + 2 - asString.Length));
        }
     } else {
        if (asString.Length > x + 1) {
           return asString.Substring(0, x + 1);
        } else {
           // Pad with zeros
           return asString.Insert(1, new String('0', x + 1 - asString.Length));
        }
     }
  }
```

Output:

```
  +1.2345
  -12.345
  -0.1234
  +1234.5
  +0.0000
  +1.1000
```

**EDIT**

Notice that it does not chop off trailing zeros.

Comment: This is different from mine, how?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Try this: `Console.WriteLine(FormatNumDigits(1.1, 5));  Console.WriteLine(ToStringWithSign(1.1, 5));`

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the EDIT before that comment.

Answer (score 4):

You mention "x characters". So we can simplify that to "x-1 digits", and just write code that shows x digits.

I think passing the ["G" numeric format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#GFormatString) to [`Double.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx) is as close to built-in as you can get.

```
double d = 1234.56789;
string s = d.ToString("G6");           // "1234.57"
```

So we just expand that to manually add the "+" at the front:

```
if (d > 0)
    s = "+" + s;
```

Putting it all together in an extension method:

**EDIT: Includes optional parameter to truncate**

```
public static string ToStringWithSign(this double d, int digits, bool truncate = false)
{
    if (truncate) {
        double factor = Math.Pow(10, digits - 1);
        d = Math.Truncate(d * factor) / factor;
    }

    string s = d.ToString("G" + digits);
    if (d > 0)
        s = "+" + s;
    return s;
}
```

Results:

```
(1234.56789).ToStringWithSign(4);      // "+1235"
(1234.56789).ToStringWithSign(5);      // "+1234.6"
(1234.56789).ToStringWithSign(6);      // "+1234.57"
(-1234.56789).ToStringWithSign(6);     // "-1234.57"

(1.2345678).ToStringWithSign(6);       // "+1.23457"
(1.2345678).ToStringWithSign(6, true); // "+1.23456"
```

Comment: I'd change that check to do "if d > 0". Some cultures don't use "-" for the negative sign.

Comment: @EstebanAraya Good call. If nothing else, it's simpler :-P. But I think if we're bringing culture into this discussion, the OP is going to have other issues, because of this specific formatting he desires anyway.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart This still isn't quite right because it rounds the value.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk rounding was never mentioned in the OP.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart All of his examples truncate instead of rounding.

Comment: This is fine people. Rounding wasn't the issue. Thanks to all that answered.

Comment: I'm not sure how the OP wants trailing 0s handled but it looks like your solution will just lob them off (0.1000 -> 0.1)

Comment: @Parker is correct, unfortunately this solution does chop em. I will look into it further, however while this is close, its not exactly right.

Answer (score 2):

If you want truncation:

```
string str = number.ToString("+0.00000;-0.00000").Substring(0,7);
```

If you want rounding:

```
string str = number.ToString("+0.0000;-0.0000");
```

EDIT: if you want, you can write a simple wrapper that takes the number of digits as a parameter:

```
string FormatDecimal(decimal value, int digits )
{
    return value
        .ToString(String.Format("+0.{0};-0.{0}", new string('0',digits - 2)))
        .Substring(0,digits+1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eren, This is very close and would actually work for my inputs, however Michaels is more generic.

Comment: @Simon Thank you. but I must say that answer unnecessarily and inefficiently duplicates what is already built-in to `ToString`.

Comment: But his takes an arbitrary number of digits as a parameter.

Comment: @Simon you could just change the number of zeros, couldn't you? but even if you wanted a wrapper method, I wouldn't duplicate the built-in stuff. See my edit, is this better?

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you want to output to 6 character inclusive of the decimal point, you can have a look at this

```
double val1 = -99.56789;
//string strval = val1.ToString("+#.######;-#.######");// add # for additional decimal places
string strval = val1.ToString("+#.000000;-#.000000");    
Console.WriteLine(strval.Substring(0,strval.Length >= 7 ? 7 : strval.Length));
 //output -99.567 if positive would output +99.567
```

You just need to transform the value to a string and then pick up the relevant 6 characters (the additional one is for the sign) from the outputted string.

There is no rounding in this case and fits your need, hope this is what you are looking out for.

Comment: Would be good to know what is wrong here, so that it could be fixed

Comment: It should be fine when using `0` instead of `#` like `#.000000`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        double myDouble = 1546.25469874;
        string myStr = string.Empty;
        if (myDouble > 0)
        {
            myStr = myDouble.ToString("+0.0###");
        }
        else
        {
            myStr = myDouble.ToString("0.0####");
        }
        if (myStr.Length > 7)
        {
            myStr = myStr.Remove(7).TrimEnd('.');
        }
```

Comment: it will return +1.0. Isn't it what you want? But 1.005 will return +1.005

Comment: No, unfortunately I always need a number with 6 characters, i.e. it should return 1.0000. It chops off the trailing zeroes

Comment: replace the #'s with zeroes and its virtually there.

Comment: yes if you need 0s to be shown also you should replace #'s with zeros )

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.  It *does* round the last digit, though.

```
static string Format(double d)
{
    // define how many number should be visible
    int digits = 5;

    // Get the left part of the number (ignore negative sign for now)
    int s = Math.Abs(d).ToString("####0").Length;

    // Total size minus the amount of numbers left of the decimal point
    int precision = digits - s;

    // Left side for positive, right side for negative.
    // All it's doing is generating as many 0s as we need for precision.
    string format = String.Format("+###0.{0};-###0.{0}", new String('0', precision));
    return d.ToString(format);
}
```

Given your input this returns:

```
+1.2346
-12.346
-0.1235
+1234.6
```

It'll handle zeros no problem:

```
+0.1000
+0.0000
+1000.0
```

Comment: @Simon Try it with `Console.WriteLine(Format(9999.9));`

Comment: Or `Console.WriteLine(Format(-999.9));`

Answer (score -2):

As stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) by MSDN, "0" is the place holder for a digit. So, all you need is:

`myDecimal.ToString("000000");`

or

`myDecimal.ToString("######");`

if you don't want a digit present instead of a zero.

Comment: Yes, but considering the decimal place is in an unknown position, how many leading/trailing zeros are there?

Comment: @Simon, you can figure out the position of the decimal point by dividing by ten until you no longer get an integer. You could then build the format string as outlined above and putting the decimal place in the correct place.

I don't know if you'll be able to do it with a predefined format string. I think you might have to build it every time. I'll keep thinking though. Good question!